# IBM MQ websphere - creates an additional TCP "ACK" and waiting 13 sec for answer

Tags: tcp, ibm-mq

I got two Tomcats with identical java apps ('clients') that communicate with a single MQ server

On one client, the communication is fast, but on the other it takes a lot of time (> 13 sec).

On the infrastructure the only difference is that the 'slow client' is on a different domain then the server, while the 'fast client' is on the same domain, which should cause any trouble, as far as I know.

I've sniffed the communication both ways with Wireshark, and I've found one difference: the MQ server sends an additional "ACK" to the slow client, does not get nothing, waits for 13 seconds and then sends the "INITIAL DATA" packet that actually starts the work, like this:

Client - > server :IBM WebSphere SYN

Server - > client :IBM WebSphere SYN-ACK

Client - > server :IBM WebSphere ACK

Client - > server :INITIAL DATA

Server - > client :IBM WebSphere ACK // only on slow client!!!

// Waits for 13 seconds - only on slow client.

Server - > client :INITIAL DATA // from here, it flows on both clients

Notes:

1) The communication to the server is not SSL, and uses IP address rather then DNS names, so resolving issues should not occur.

2) I've published a similar question before - this is not the same case! last time it was BIOS over TCP issue.

Comment: The MQ server doesn't send ACKs. The TCP/IP stack in the OS sends ACKs. You should therefore stop thinking about application servers altogether and start thinking about network conditions and configurations. Which puts the question off-topic.

Comment: @EJP if something in the MQ configuration causes this behavior, it's MQ issue. Anyhow, we worked-around it with connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way we used to overcome the issue is using SimpleConnctionManager and a long timeout.

It's a work around, but it works.